# How to check the version of Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel

I would like to know how to check the version of Laravel Livewire.
I'm planning to update Livewire and would like to check the current version.

Comment: It's in your `composer.json` I'd guess

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`composer show` will list all the installed packages and their current version

Comment: Awesome! That's what I wanted to know. So now I can know the versions of other packages. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `composer.json` and in `require` property you will see the livewire version like:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
        ...
    },
    ...
```